# Where does a python decorator get the arguments from the decorated function

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have this code:

```
def foo(bar):
    def test(some_string):
        return 'Decorator test: '+bar(some_string)
    return test


def main():
    print(bar('test1'))


@foo
def bar(some_string):
    return some_string[:3]
```

I understand that calling `bar('test1)` is basically calling `foo(bar('test1'))`, but when I try to print `some_string` in `foo` before the other function, I get `some_string is not defined`:

```
def foo(bar):
    print(some_string)
    def test(some_string):
        return 'Decorator test: '+bar(some_string)
    return test
```

1. How does `test` know about `some_string` while `foo` doesn't?
2. Why do I have to return `test` for the decorator to work? returning directly `Decorator test: '+bar(some_string)` doesn't work as `some_string` is not defined.

Comment: Nope. It's `foo(bar)('test1')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand that calling `bar('test1)` is basically calling `foo(bar('test1'))`

No, it is not, your understanding is incorrect. It is basically calling

```
foo(bar)('test')
```

The `@foo` decorator syntax tells Python to call `foo()` passing in the function object named by `bar` (and the result is assigned back to the name `bar`).

The `foo()` decorator returned a new function object:

```
def test(some_string):
    # ...
return test
```

So the result of `foo(bar)` is that function object named `test` (a local name in the `foo()` decorator). `foo(bar)('test')` thus called `test('test')`.

If you wanted to print the argument passed to `test(..)`, do so *inside* that function:

```
def foo(bar):
    def test(some_string):
        print(some_string)
        return 'Decorator test: '+bar(some_string)
    return test
```

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that calling `bar('test1)` is basically calling `foo(bar('test1'))`

No, that is incorrect.

Calling `bar('test1')` is equivalent to

```
bar = foo(bar)
bar('test1')
```

> Why do I have to return `test` for the decorator to work? returning directly Decorator test: '+bar(some_string) doesn't work as some_string is not defined.

When you do

```
@decorator
def func():
    pass
```

Python translates it to

```
def func():
    pass

func = decorator(func)
```

As you can see, Python expects `decorator` to return a **new** function. This is why you must return `test` from `foo` for `bar` to work correctly. Otherwise, `None` is assigned to `bar`:

```
>>> def foo(bar):
    def test(some_string):
        return 'Decorator test: '+bar(some_string)


>>> @foo
def bar(some_string):
    return some_string[:3]

>>> bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    bar()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

> How does test know about some_string while foo doesn't?

Simply because `some_string` isn't created until `test` is reached. `some_string` is a parameter of `test`, so it exists only in the scope of `test`. Otherwise, no name `some_string` exist, so  you'll get a `NameError` if you try to access it - including inside of `foo`.

If you want to `print` the value of `some_string`, do so inside of `test`:

```
def foo(bar):
    def test(some_string):
        print(some_string)
        return 'Decorator test: '+bar(some_string)
    return test
```